# Почему код из Java Concurrency in Practice считается безопасным

Tags: java, concurrency

читаю книгу Java Concurrency in Practice и один пример "безопасного" кода из 3 главы насторожил меня. В книге сказано, что использование volatile-переменных в связке с неизменяемыми объектами могут обеспечить слабую форму атомарности и дан пример с факторизацией числа. Дан класс-холдер, который
содержит число и его факторы, должен служить "кэшем".

```
@Immutable
class OneValueCache {
     private final BigInteger lastNumber;
     private final BigInteger[] lastFactors;
     public OneValueCache(BigInteger i, BigInteger[] factors) {
         lastNumber = i;
         lastFactors = Arrays.copyOf(factors, factors.length);
     }
     public BigInteger[] getFactors(BigInteger i) {
         if (lastNumber == null || !lastNumber.equals(i))
             return null;
         else
             return Arrays.copyOf(lastFactors, lastFactors.length);
     }
}
```

Также дан сервлет, который на вход получает число и должен отдать факторы этого числа, и если на входе сервлет два раза подряд получает одно и тоже число, то в первый раз он кэширует само число и его факторы, а во второй - просто достает из кэша. Код ниже.

```
@ThreadSafe
public class VolatileCachedFactorizer implements Servlet {
     private volatile OneValueCache cache = new OneValueCache(null, null);
     public void service(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp) {
         BigInteger i = extractFromRequest(req);
         BigInteger[] factors = cache.getFactors(i);
         if (factors == null) {
             factors = factor(i);
             cache = new OneValueCache(i, factors);
         }
         encodeIntoResponse(resp, factors);
     }
}
```

Дело в том, что я не могу понять, почему такой код считается безопасным? Допустим поток А принимает число 8, записывает в конструкторе класса OneValueCache lastNumber = 8; и зависает(условно). В то же время, поток В тоже получает число 8, пытается получить факторы числа 8 в строке BigInteger[] factors = cache.getFactors(i) класса VolatileCachedFactorizer и, выполняя этот метод, видит, что условие if (lastNumber == null || !lastNumber.equals(i)) не соблюдается и поэтому возвращает return Arrays.copyOf(lastFactors, lastFactors.length); Но поток А все еще висит и он не успел записать факторы числа 8, поэтому lastFactors все еще null, следовательно вызов Arrays.copyOf(lastFactors, lastFactors.length) привет к НПЕ. Поправьте меня, пожалуйста, где я ошибся?

Comment: мне не ясно, как вот это `new OneValueCache(null, null);` отработает, если у него внутри `lastFactors = Arrays.copyOf(factors, factors.length);` ?\

Comment: По поводу того, что вы спрашиваете, то мне кажется, что если первый поток зависнет в конструкторе тут `cache = new OneValueCache(i, factors);`, то переменная `cache` не получит значение до тех пор, пока конструктор не завершится. То есть если конструктор еще не выполнен, то объекст считай ещё не создан и не хранится ни в какой переменной, а значит другой поток не может его использовать. В вашем сценарии второй поток просто использует предыдущее значение переменной `cache`, а когда первый поток таки выполнит конструктор, то первый поток перезапишет `cache` новым значением.

Comment: @tym32167, мне кажется проще сказать, что присвоение  переменной другой ссылки является атомарной операцией.

Comment: @Mister_Jesus вопрос не про атомарное присвоение, а про то, что пока конструктор не выполнился, никакого присвоения не происходит.

Comment: @tym32167, я ещё раз перечитал вопрос. Я тогда дополню (Не вам):  `lastNumber` будет для каждого потока свой, так как каждый поток создаст свой объект класса `OneValueCache` при условии, что оба прошли условие на null в методе `service`. До момента присвоения они не видят другой экземпляр этого класса.